# read from second line from a binary file C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have a  file containing A heading followed by the encrypted data. I need to ignore the 1st line (heading ) and read the rest of the file and then decrypt. I am doing this in C++. How do i go about it. I have tried getLine,  but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Expand on "doesn't seem to work". Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: How do you define "line" in a binary file? How is the heading terminated? What sequence of bytes signifies this?

Comment: In a binary file, there is no concept of a "line". `'\n'` is nothing but byte `0xa` as far as a binary file is concerned.

Comment: If the 1st line is terminated by a single byte delimiter, you can use [`std::istream::ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip the 1st line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There are variety of file formats which start with a human-readable text line terminated by a LF or even CRLF (used as magic code) and then continue with "binary noise"... ;-)

Comment: Just skip the amount of bytes the header occupies. There is no "line" in binary

Comment: @Scheff Yes, but the author has to define what that terminator is, as there is no inherent "line" concept in a binary file to do it for you.